# Declaration of model in Razor View in mvc4 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net mvc4 and there is something i don't understand well.

Why do I have to declare the Model using @model at top of the view, if I already pass an object to the View in the controller.

Taking an example :

Controller:

```
public ActionResult countryDetails(int id)
    {

        Country country = db.Country.Find(id);
        return View(country);

    }
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Country
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "countryDetails";
}
...
```

The controller returns a View with an object as parameter, so the model should be already known. I'm sorry if it is obvious, but I can't figure out why this is not a "double" declaration.

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 7):

The declaration at the top will do two things for you:

- It will allow intellisence to know what type you are using when you type in @Model or use any of the Html helper extensions.
- It will also check at runtime that model passed in can be cast to the type the view expects.

Its not necessarily a "double declaration" as it is analogous to specifying a type to a parameter on a method. Like so

```
Person Someone = new Person();
RenderView(Someone);
...
void RenderView(Person model) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I got it now :)

Answer (score 4):

By default your view inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>`

You can optionally override this class, it's default ASP.NET inheritance mechanism:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<List<CompanyName.MyProduct.MyCategory>>
```

Or you can just simplify this since MVC3 like this:

```
@model List<CompanyName.MyProduct.MyCategory>
```

This sugar syntax was made to simplify code typing.
This declaration give you some things

1. View automatically cast object to the preferred type
2. You receive type-defined 'model' property which allows you to access
   to your object methods and properties

Just believe that this is a method which accepts object and cast it to the specified type that you provide

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is type-safety, it allows you to work with strongly typed views with the benefit of intellisense, compiler error hints, invalid casting etc.

Also, another reason is for readability - it acts as a reminder to what sort of model it is you are actually dealing with instead of having to keep referring back to the controller.